# Como subir mi pagina web a AWS

Tags: php, mvc, vscode, aws, macos

Acabo de terminar un proyecto de una pagina web con php, con una estructura de MVC, y contrate AWS para subirlo, pero no se por donde empezar. Alguna ayuda o sugerencia?

Espero poder configurar bien la Base de Datos, crear los archivos necesarios para no tener problemas a futuro

Comment: Pues si no tienes mucha idea de AWS, lo primero es formarte. AWS es muy complejo, tiene decenas de servicios que interactuan entre sí. Te sugiero no depender de un foro para montar un servicio web de 0 en AWS. Piensa que los errores que cometas los vas a pagar con dinero de tu bolsillo, eso si no guardas datos de usuarios y acaba llamando protección de datos a tu puerta. Tómatelo con calma y fórmate en AWS antes de desplegar nada, te lo curarás en salud

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos.